# How to open usual chrome or Firefox window while using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When you start a Web-driver using Selenium, It opens a new and very fresh instance of respective web browser ( looks as if just installed, no history and default settings}.

Is there any way to open usual windows which will have customized settings which I have done in my chrome or Firefox like add-ons and all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use existing profile in FireFox

```
File profileDir = new File("Path to default profile")
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);    
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

For Chrome, you can go with options as below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: But in that case , you are actually adding setting to your new instance. I am interested if we can open the old usual windows only. Suppose there is some intranet links which does not open on new instances ( security purpose), But works fine on usual browser windows.

Comment: @Manish Updated answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks. It gave error while File.But FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\mkh6kor\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\rwyq8vbx.default");  Worked like charm.

Comment: Any idea how to do the same in python? @nitinchawda